# Extra space on top and bottom of Init View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I have a swift app I have been working on for some time now. I noticed that my init view controller has extra space at the top and the bottom of the view, so much that it allows me to pull up and down on the first view and let go and have it spring back into where it was. I removed all my constraints thinking I had an issue with them, but it's still done the same thing. The size class is set to any any, and all my graphic fit inside the view, yet I still an able to pull up and down.

I also made sure my view, wasn't a scroll view, it's not.

I looked around for similar issues, but couldn't find anything like this.

Thanks for the help!

Here is what my view looks like in IB
[image]

When I run the app.
[image]

Showing the amount I am able to pull it down from the top.

[image]

Comment: Please attach screenshots of your simulator and your storyboard

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all of your constraints, and the storyboard is set to use auto layout, it usually won't show up correctly, as you have seen.  You will have to add the constraints to each element in your view controller.  To do that, you can control click on each and drag it where you want to connect a constraint.  Or, use the pin and align buttons in the bottom right corner of the storyboard view.

There is a good [tutorial from apple that I suggest you read](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW1).  It will help you with the basics of using auto layout.  Another option would be to not use auto layout. To turn it off in the Storyboard, go to the file inspector and uncheck the box "Use Auto Layout".